# Adding content of a cell into a string variable in VBA. Also, adding cells below it using offset

Tags: vba, excel, offset

I have a simple function that is going to pull from a specific Cell (N4). If there are cells below it then it will loop and collect all the content of the cell and separate with comma.

I'm getting `#VALUE!` error in excel right now and I kind of know where my issue lies but can not figure how to fix it, since I am not that proficient with `excel-vba` code. I think the issue is with `ActiveSheet.Range("N4").Value` and the offset part.

I am not sure how to offset then select the value in the text then add it to my string Value.
Any thought on how I can select the content of cell and add to string variable and doing the same when you offset?

Here is my code:

```
Function pullshit() As String

Dim output As String
Dim counter As Integer

counter = 1

output = ActiveSheet.Range("N4").Value

If Application.offset(N4, counter, 0).Value = "" Then

    pullshit = output

Else
    While counter <> 0
        output = output + ", " + Application.offset(N4, counter, 0).Value
        counter = counter + 1

        If Application.offset(N4, counter, 0) = "" Then
            counter = 0
        End If
    Wend

    pullshit = output

End If

End Function
```

Comment: Your `Offset` calls are invalid.

Comment: How should I be calling my `Offset`? @chrisneilsen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Offset use is wrong. Try this.

```
Function pullshit() As String

Dim output As String
Dim counter As Integer

counter = 1

output = ActiveSheet.Range("N4").Value

If Range("N4").Offset(counter, 0).Value = "" Then

    pullshit = output

Else
    While counter <> 0
        output = output + ", " + Range("N4").Offset(counter, 0).Value
        counter = counter + 1

        If Range("N4").Offset(counter, 0) = "" Then
            counter = 0
        End If
    Wend

    pullshit = output

End If

End Function
```

Use of the function in a screenshot
[image]

Comment: For some reason after making this update I am getting a `#NAME?` error in excel.

Comment: I just tried in a new file and it worked out fine. Thank you much.